# Recognise list comprehension type

Tags: python, mypy

Take this following code:

```py
from typing import Union

value: Union[str, bytes]
stripped = [line.strip() for line in value.splitlines()]

reveal_type(stripped)
```

To anyone reading, it's clear that `stripped` should be of type

```
Union[List[str], List[bytes]]
```

However, `mypy` recognised it as

```
List[Union[str, bytes]]
```

How can I get `mypy` to recognise it as `Union[List[str], List[bytes]]`?

Comment: I don't see the issue. You have a list of union types, not a union of list types

Comment: if `value` is `str`, then `stripped` will be a list of `str`. If `value` is `bytes`, then `stripped` will be a list of `bytes`. There's no other possibilites, are there?

Comment: The list is a list. Period. Therefore, that is the type of `stripped`. Each element is either `str` or `bytes`

Comment: yeah but I know that either all elements are `str`, or all elements are `bytes`. Is there no way to tell `mypy` this?

Comment: I guess you could try and force it `stripped: Union[List[str], List[bytes]] = [...]`

Comment: @OneCricketeer it's a list comprehension rather than a list (I'm sure you know I'm just highlighting it). Perhaps OP is thinking that mypy might be clever enough to understand that can be used here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```py
from typing import Union

value: Union[str, bytes]
stripped_str =[]

if isinstance(value, str):
    stripped_str = [line.strip() for line in value.splitlines()]
else:
    stripped_bytes = [line.strip() for line in value.splitlines()]

stripped = stripped_str or stripped_bytes

reveal_type(stripped)
```

So that Mypy finds the type of `stripped` is `Union[list[str], list[bytes]]`.